# Connect to specific port range in Asterisk Server from JsSIP front end

Tags: webrtc, jssip

JsSIP is currently trying to connect to audio (after accepting incoming call) to random ports over UDP. How can I restrict it to a specific to a port range for the audio?

Edit: Log from Asterisk
Exp:m=audio 63485 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 8 107 0 101 (here we got port 63485 which is out of range )

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk port range for media should be configured in `rtp.conf`

default:

```
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=20000
```

Comment: After doing this, the client side tries to connect to random ports, leading to no audio